# Possible to add 240V plug to my condo electric outside?

Tags: electrical

This is obviously not something I plan to DIY, but just curious if it is feasible.  I'm in a third floor condo and wondering if I'd be able to setup an EV charger by my parking, which happens to be near the main electric supply for the building.  My plan would be to have a box with a 240V plug, like a NEMA 14-30, that I could plug a mobile J1772 in to when needed.

As you can see, there are meters for 6 residential units.  I'm on the bottom left of those, with one 100A breaker off the meter in the box just to the left.  Ideally, I'd run a 32 amp charger, but could definitely get by with 24 amps.  Hot water is provided by the building, so interior electric needs are minimal.  A 30 amp breaker for the dryer, 30 amp for the stove.  I have no problem no charging the car if we happen to be using those simulanteously.

Let's assume I get buy in from the HOA.  Don't want to start the conversation if it's not going to work anyway.

[image: Picture of meters and main electric supply]

Comment: I think the intention was clear, but I'm hoping I don't need to put a breaker in my panel on the third floor then somehow run from there all the way back down.  Wondering if there is a way to do it all from the ground.  Any other clever ideas welcome, though.

Comment: I'm in Colorado, and believe there is a law supporting installation of EV chargers in condos based on stipulations like I pay for installation, it meets aesthetic requirements, etc.

Comment: Your car is presumably away from the parking spot for periods of time....Are you concerned about others parking there and plugging in?

Comment: I'd be inclined to add a 7th meter specifically for electric vehicle charging instead of pulling it off your meter. That way it's much easier to add more outlets for future expansion. Do you know how big the main breaker is?

Comment: @MichaelKaras, somewhat, but if it's a 240v plug in a box, it's a little less enticing than a full charger set up and ready to use.  I'd also look in to whether the box for the plug could be locked.  Not a deal breaker if it can't.

Comment: @user3757614  I don't, unfortunately.  I'll have to look later, but it won't be for a while, I left last night and won't be back for a week.  I assume you are picturing some shared EV charging meter with a cost break down between EV owners in the building?  Otherwise, having two meters just for me seems overly complicated.  That might be a better solution for the building, but I imagine it would be more work and buy in up front.

Comment: Yeah, I'm picturing a shared EV charging meter. I'm also thinking that your meter doesn't really have the free amperage needed to do this properly, which would make pulling off it more complicated.

Comment: Ideally you could talk the HOA into getting an additional panel installed, with maybe 100 A to dedicate to at least 3  (30 A) charging outlets.  That would be very forward-thinking & avoid multiple reworks as the number of BEVs grows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can tee off it, with 100A rated wire (3Cu/1Al).

Also, the run to the apartment will have to be upgraded to that.  It is no longer entitled to the 83% "whole service" derate, since it's no longer carrying tge whole service.

And then, carry it over to a 100A subpanel.  There, you have appropriate breakers for your charger.

Comment: Thanks Harper.  I obviously have no idea what wire got run in the first place all the way up.  Do you think the conduit is likely continuous and it would be an easy change?  What if my condo breaker got bumped down to 80 amp or 90 amp?  I'm trying to picture what this would look like.  There'd be a sub panel somewhere near the meters, and the current condo feeder would go to that?  So outside, I'd have a breaker panel with the condo breaker and breaker for the plug.  Nice.

Comment: You could fork the main feed, since it's after the breaker, so your condo feed wouldn't need to visit the sub.  That would let you put the sub where convenient, e.g. An RV subpanel which includes the receptacle, or a simple 2-space subpanel.